# How does RestTemplate make use of HttpEntity with a generic body?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Hoping to get some help in finding how `RestTemplate.exchange()` can take in a `HttpEntity` with a generic body type such as: `HttpEntity(T body, MultiValueMap<String,String> headers)`

How do I know how `RestTemplate.exchange()` makes use of my `HttpEntity` with my own custom object type body? Is it calling a `.toString()` on whatever object the body is? How can I confirm that's how it works? Thanks for any help!

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpEntity.html

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html

Comment: It uses [`HttpMessageConverter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/HttpMessageConverter.html).

Comment: I assume you are curious on how it works instead of just using it. The easiest way is to see the code if it is available. If it is not, it probably uses the methods defined by the superclass or the interfaces. Or, it could use introspection to do that. Apart from curiosity sake, I wouldn’t bother how it works, but that it works correctly.